# Why is this undefined within reactjs component method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple search bar which uses a react-autosuggest. When I create a suggestion, I want to attach an onClick handler. This onClick has been passed down from a parent class. When the suggestion is rendered however, `this` is undefined and therefore the click handler is not attached.

I have attached the component below, the logic which is not working is in the `renderSuggestion` method.

```
import Autosuggest from 'react-autosuggest'
import React from 'react'


export class SearchBar extends React.Component {
     static getSuggestionValue(suggestion) {
        return suggestion;
    }


    static escapeRegexCharacters(str) {
        return str.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value: '',
            suggestions: [],
            listOfValues: this.props.tickers
        };

    }

    onChange = (event, { newValue, method }) => {
        this.setState({
            value: newValue
        });
    };

    onSuggestionsFetchRequested = ({ value }) => {
        this.setState({
            suggestions: this.getSuggestions(value)
        });
    };

    onSuggestionsClearRequested = () => {
        this.setState({
            suggestions: []
        });
    };

    renderSuggestion(suggestion) {
        return (
            <span onClick={() => this.props.clickHandler(suggestion)}>{suggestion}</span>
        );
    }



    getSuggestions(value) {
        const escapedValue = SearchBar.escapeRegexCharacters(value.trim());

        if (escapedValue === '') {
            return [];
        }

        const regex = new RegExp('^' + escapedValue, 'i');

        return this.state.listOfValues.filter(ticker => regex.test(ticker));
    }



    render() {
        const { value, suggestions } = this.state;
        const inputProps = {
            placeholder: "Search for stocks...",
            value,
            onChange: this.onChange
        };

        return (
            <Autosuggest
                suggestions={suggestions}
                onSuggestionsFetchRequested={this.onSuggestionsFetchRequested}
                onSuggestionsClearRequested={this.onSuggestionsClearRequested}
                getSuggestionValue={SearchBar.getSuggestionValue}
                renderSuggestion={this.renderSuggestion}
                inputProps={inputProps} />
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is becuase you need to bind "this" to your function.
If you add this code to your constructor

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        value: '',
        suggestions: [],
        listOfValues: this.props.tickers
    };
    //this line of code binds this to your function so you can use it
    this.renderSuggestion = this.renderSuggestion.bind(this);

}
```

It should work. More info can be found at https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 0):

In the scope of `renderSuggestion`, `this` isn't referring to the instance of the class.

Turning `renderSuggestion` into an arrow function like you've done elsewhere will ensure that `this` refers to the instance of the class.

```
renderSuggestion = (suggestion) => {
        return (
            <span onClick={() => this.props.clickHandler(suggestion)}>{suggestion}</span>
        );
    }
```

Comment: Ahhh brilliant spot! Thanks :)

Comment: This works in terms of now `this` is defined. However, the click handler is still not being attached within the span, any ideas?

Comment: Can you log something to the console in the `onClick`? If that logs then you know the handler is being called. Getting any errors in the console etc? Is `this.props.clickHandler` really a function?

Comment: Sorted it. Thanks for the help.